Movie about a warrior who goes to the underworld
I am trying to find a movie but remember it vaguely. 
Plot: 
It is about a warrior who goes to the underworld to take something that can kill the villain in the film. 
Plot points: This movie is historical and I think this "something" is in some kind of underworld where it is said that this underworld contains uncountable riches, horrors etc and the hero along with others travel to this under world to take something. Some of them die in this under world. The entrance to this under world is in the palace where the hero breaks-in. There is also a witch or lady magician who aids villain and gives him power at end by having sex with him, to transform into some kind of beast and the villain fights hero at the end using this power.I think the power is some insect power like scorpion.
Movie set period: It is set during times where king ruled 
Movie type: Fiction 
Language: English 
Movie format: Colour

If it was animated (or CGI) I would think that it could be Beowolf, the one with Sean bean as a voice.

Was it by any chance The Scorpion King (2002)?

A desert warrior rises up against the evil army that is destroying his homeland. He captures the enemy's key sorcerer, takes her deep into the desert and prepares for a final showdown.

Why I think this is it:

Movie set period: It is set during times where king ruled 

It's the name of the movie, and the "Scorpion King" is what the protagonist ends up as.

There is also a witch or lady magician who aids villain and gives him power at end by having sex with him, to transform into some kind of beast 

He captures the enemy's key sorcerer, takes her deep into the desert and prepares for a final showdown. I'm not sure about the occurrence of sex, but I wouldn't be surprised if that was foisted onto the plot (which wasn't great to begin with).

to transform into some kind of beast and the villain fights hero at the end using this power. I think the power is some insect power like scorpion.

He ends up as the Scorpion King instead of the villain (who wanted to become the Scorpion King), which turns him into scorpion-like monster.
We actually meet him as the Scorpion King in an earlier movie, The Mummy Returns. The Scorpion King was actually made after The Mummy Returns, to create a sort of origin story.
Screenshot of the Scorpion King:


Some of them die in this under world. The entrance to this under world is in the palace where the hero breaks-in.

From the synopsis:  Cassandra has a vision of Memnon and his army slaughtering the entire rebel camp. She informs Mathayus and then prophesies that when the moonlight reaches the Memnon's palace, the King on High will become the invincible Scorpion King, and Memnon believes himself to be the one destined to become the Scorpion King.
It's not so much that the entrance is in the palace, but rather that the supernatural phenomenom occurs in the palace.

This movie is historical and I think this "something" is in some kind of underworld where it is said that this underworld contains uncountable riches, horrors etc and the hero along with others travel to this under world to take something. Some of them die in this under world.

I think that you're referring to The Mummy Returns here. It's a historical movie, where the protagonists end up in an underworld where them and Imhotep (the movie's villain) face off against the Scorpion King (who has been living in this underworld since the events of The Scorpion King movie).
The reconstructed storyline:
The Scorpion King

Mathayus is in a bloody conflict with Memnon, the movie villain.
Mathayus ends up working with Memnon's sorceress. She assists him and tells him her visions.
There is a supernatural event at Memnon's palace, where Memnon assumes he will become the Scorpion King.
Mathayus intervenes, defeats the villain, and ends up becoming the Scorpion King himself.

The Mummy Returns

The protagonists explore ancient Egyptian ruins.
They are chasing/being chased by the movie villain, who had been a mummy (but now looks human), who wants the power of the Scorpion King for himself.
People die on the way to the Scorpion king's underground lair.
Everyone faces off agains the Scorpion King (monster Mathayus) in the movie's climax.


Yes it is.Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation
